# Second monitor with separate input

Tags: winforms, lua, keyboard, touch, pipeline

I am currently programming my own interface with WinForms.
As the main application, a program runs on the main monitor (no touch), which should be controllable with the mouse and keyboard. The self-programmed interface runs on the second monitor (touch) and should only be operated with touch.
Now I would like to make settings with touch on the second monitor, but at the same time stay in the main application and work there with the mouse and keyboard.
There is also a connection between the two applications via lua and Visual Studio.

How can I change the WinForm so that I don't leave the main program when I touch it?

I would be very happy about a solution.

I tried with VirtualBox, but there I no longer have a connection between the main program and my application.

Comment: So, you want a Form that doesn't activate (hence, become the foreground Window and move the Focus to a child Control), but it's operable with touch. You have to override some default behavior, in relation to the activation of a Window: `ShowWithoutActivation` to always return `true` and `DefWndProc` to trap `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` and return `MA_NOACTIVATE` as `Result` (without calling base) -- All Controls must have `SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);` in their Constructor -- Edit Controls (e.g., TextBox) need an OSK to enter text

Comment: Sounds vaguely similar to a [multiseat configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiseat_configuration).